# Does non-calibrated have a special meaning for guitar strings?

Tags: electric-guitar, strings

I'm puzzled by the following. It seems to imply that "non-calibrated" strings are a good idea.

> Steinberger double-ball strings have, as the name suggests, string
> balls at both ends of the string. This makes them ultra-easy to
> install on Steinberger instruments using the front-mounted tailpiece
> and headless tuning system.
>
> The double-ball ***non-calibrated*** design ensures easy installation and
> contributes to the reputable Steinberger tuning stability. This
> particular Light-gauge pack is designed for Steinberger’s 6-string
> guitars.
> https://www.andertons.co.uk/steinberger-6-string-doubleball-guitar-strings-light

Here's a definition of calibrate

> 4: to adjust precisely for a particular function 
> 5: to measure precisely
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calibrated

You would think that calibration is a good thing.

Is there some special meaning of non-calibrated when referring to guitar strings?

Comment: I’m only guessing that earlier steinberger models might have required calibrated strings which would likely have been more expensive. So it could be a positive marketing point to support non-calibrated strings on current guitars.

Comment: There are calibrated strings for trans-trem. When you think about it, it makes sense that having specific string gauges and lengths might be required to make the trans trem system work as intended: https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/SST106--steinberger-sst-106

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The term is related to Steinberger's [TransTrem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TransTrem) tremolo system, which requires strings of a specific length to work properly- the strings are "calibrated" for use with this system.  Any other set of strings would then be "non-calibrated", and the strings are marked as such so TransTrem users don't buy the wrong set.

[Here is another information page.](http://www.steinbergerworld.com/tt_tips.htm)

And a quote from [one reseller](https://www.headlessusa.com/guitar-strings) explains it (emphasis added):

> The "STP" series are specially calibrated for the TransTrem transposing tremolo system used on the vast majority of existing original USA-built Steinberger GL, GP, and GM series guitars. These strings feature two standard ball-ends and are **built to exacting lengths** to ensure accurate functioning and tuning of the TransTrem tremolo version #2.

Comment: Thanks for solving that - I have a Steinberger Spirit. When I depress the arm, the chord goes out of tune. I wasn't particularly worried about that. I'm now wondering if I were to buy the calibrated strings, the chord would stay in tune despite the pitch bend. The bridge assembly is simply marked as .*"Steinberger System - Under license - Pat. Pending."* -  I'll see if I can follow this up myself but any insights from others would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for solving that - I have a Steinberger Spirit (should have mentioned that earlier!). When I depress the arm, the chord goes out of tune. I wasn't particularly worried about that. I'm now wondering if I were to buy the calibrated strings, the chord would stay in tune despite the pitch bend. The bridge assembly is simply marked as .*"Steinberger System - Under license - Pat. Pending."* -  I'll see if I can follow this up myself but any insights from others would be appreciated.  Here's a pic.https://www.gak.co.uk/en/steinberger-spirit-gt-pro-quilt-top-deluxe-outfit-wine-red/918867